# Как переделать Спеки с учетом cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Как переделать тесты с учетом cancan, чтобы создавать/редактировать Airport мог только пользователь с ролью robot и admin, а удалять только пользователь с ролью admin?
Сам Airport что-то типа справочника и ассоциаций с User не имеет
Сейчас response.body содержит  `error: You are not authorized to access this` page.
Собственно вопрос как мне  в тестах сделать запрос от пользователя с нужной ролью

Есть Ability

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all

elsif user.robot?
  can [:read, :search, :create, :update], Flight
  can [:read, :create, :update], Airport

elsif user.operator?
  can [:read, :search], Flight
  can :read, Airport

else # not logged in
  can [:read, :search], Flight
  can :read, Airport
end

есть User

def admin?
  self.role == 'admin'
end

def robot?
  self.role == 'robot'
end
```

Есть Spec

```
 describe 'POST /create' do
    let(:access_token) { create(:access_token) }
    let(:user) { User.find(access_token.resource_owner_id) }

    it_behaves_like 'Api Authenticable'

    context 'authorized' do
      context 'with valid attributes' do
        before { post '/api/v1/airports', format: :json, access_token: access_token.token, airport: attributes_for(:airport, :airport_random) }

        it 'responses with 201' do
          expect(response.status).to eq 201
        end

        it 'creates new airport' do
          expect { response }.to change(Airport, :count).by 1
        end
      end

      context 'with invalid attributes' do
        before { post '/api/v1/airports', format: :json, access_token: access_token.token, airport: { name: nil, iata: nil } }

        it 'responses with 422' do
          expect(response.status).to eq 422
        end

        it 'doesnt create new airport' do
          expect { response }.to_not change(Airport, :count)
        end
      end
    end

    def do_request(options = {})
      post '/api/v1/airports', { format: :json }.merge(options)
    end
  end

  describe 'PUT /update' do
    let(:access_token) { create(:access_token) }
    let(:user) { User.find(access_token.resource_owner_id) }
    let(:airport) { create(:airport, :airport_random) }

    before do
      put "/api/v1/airports/#{airport.id}", format: :json,
                                            access_token: access_token.token,
                                            airport: { name: 'New Airport', country: 'New Country' }
    end

    it 'returns 200 status' do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it 'returns list of airports' do
      expect(response.body).to have_json_size(1).at_path('airport/')
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE /destroy' do
    let(:access_token) { create(:access_token) }
    let(:user) { User.find(access_token.resource_owner_id) }
    let(:airport) { create(:airport, :airport_random) }

    context 'unauthorized' do
      before { delete "/api/v1/airports/#{airport.id}", format: :json, access_token: 1234, airport: attributes_for(:airport, :airport_random) }

      it 'returns 401 status if there is invalid access token' do
        expect(response.status).to eq 401
      end

      it 'do not deleted airport' do
        expect { response }.to_not change(Airport, :count)
      end
    end

    context 'authorized' do
      context 'with valid attributes' do
        before { delete "/api/v1/airports/#{airport.id}", format: :json, access_token: access_token.token, airport: airport }

        it 'responses with 201' do
          expect(response.status).to eq 201
        end

        it 'delete airport' do
          expect { response }.to change(Airport, :count).by(-1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

есть Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :access_token, class: Doorkeeper::AccessToken do
    application { create(:oauth_application) }
    resource_owner_id { create(:user).id }
  end
end  

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@test.com" }
    password '12345678'
    password_confirmation '12345678'
    role 'visitor'
  end
end
```

Comment: саму роль я меняю добавлением в before код `user.update!(role: 'admin') ` но у мня не получается в принципе сделать запрос от аутентифицированного пользователя

Comment: А для аутентификации како-то гем используете?

Comment: Использую Devise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось добавлением в `class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController`

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_resource_owner)
end
```